# How reliable is a daisy-chained USB bus? What are the risks and how can they be minimised?

Tags: usb, bus, reliability

### Introduction

USB has been around for quite a long time now, used extensively even in the automotive, marine and space industries to some extent. However certain communication ways are more reliable than others in terms of:

- Possibility of hot redundancy
- Protection of the connected equipment against failures in other connections (surges, short circuits, misbehaviours [data, voltage levels, timing...]...) or in the hub/switch itself
- Large mean time before failure ("freeze" or hardware failure)

Usually, the error rate is a bit less important as detection and correction (which may require retransmission) is handled by the protocol library/stack.

### Question

I would like to know how reliable is a system based on a USB hub (say, 16 ports, be it daisy chained or not). What can commonly go wrong, and what could be done (protections/topologies...) to prevent single point failures from spreading (ideally I would just swap the faulty equipment and it would be ready to go).

### Specific problem

For a specific piece of equipment at work I need to interface 16 devices to both a primary PC and a redundant PC (taking over if the other one crashes). 75% of the devices have both Ethernet and USB and 25% are only USB, and I'm wondering if I should simplify everything (which may increase reliability as well) by using USB alone or have both to maximise reliability. For USB, switching between the 2 computers would be done using a manual switch.

To illustrate, the hub I'm considering is [this one](http://www.coolgear.com/product/16-port-usb-3-0-metal-hub-surge-protection-din-rail-mounting-kit), handling  < 350W surges but doesn't seem isolated; I have the hunch they're overusing the term "industrial" so I may switch it for several daisy chained 7 ports. The connected equipment is a bunch of industrial PID temperature controllers, a UPS and a  precision thermometer. However this question is more of a general one.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd describe USB as "less complex" than Ethernet.  True, TCP/IP is non-trivial, but have you ever looked into the details of USB?  In any case, TCP/IP is an easy pick for failover.

Comment: Ethernet is galvanically isolated, USB isn't. If you're worried about surges then USB is far more likely to propagate failures than Ethernet.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The thing is, I simplified the problem saying all the devices were USB/Ethernet. In fact, 75% are both, and the remaining 25% are only USB (modified my question). I can have both networks/busses, but it needs to be justified. When they say that the hub is surge protected, does that mean it's isolated as well just like ethernet?

Comment: Use Ethernet USB hosts, for example [this one](http://www.digi.com/products/usb/anywhereusb#specs) to attach the 25% of USB devices to your network.

Comment: I have already looked at network attached USB hubs, and I concluded that it was complexifying too much to the point where it becomes less reliable - if one computer crashes while connected to the hub, the other one can't get a hold of the unit.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that surges are a concern for cascade failures; it is also true that USB is not galvanically isolated by default, and in fact is a pain in the rump to isolate due to its half-duplex, bidirectional, differential-but-not-always (blast the SE0!) nature.  Thankfully, the good folks at Analog Devices stepped up and put together the [ADuM4160](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM4160.pdf) to take care of all of the truly *hard* parts of USB isolation -- while it only supports low or full speed operation, and cannot pass low/full speed negotiation signals, meaning it can't be built into a general purpose isolated USB "lump" without help, it is still the closest thing to a generic USB isolator available.

Assuming that a reliable 5V supply to the hubs is available, and preferably one 5V supply per hub (not hard!), I would split the hubs into 4 ports each and isolate the upstream port for each hub -- pick your favorite hub chipset here.  Along with good per-port surge suppression, for which I'd specify a pair of Bourns TBU devices in series with D+/D- and a shunt low-capacitance, high-energy suppressor in addition to a MOV and TVSS clamp + current limiter or PPTC for Vbus and the obligatory TVSS/clamp network for D+/D-, this should limit the propagation of surges through the USB network.

Comment: Note the serious bandwidth restrictions, though. No 480Mbps mode with isolated USB unless you do something custom and fancy.

Comment: @user2943160 -- I already noted them here (480Mbps = high-speed mode, and the ADuM4160 only supports low-speed and full-speed).  For the OP's devices though, the bandwidth situation is not critical whatsoever, and this should do him just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I work in the I.T. dept at my workplace and many people at my workplace run several devices at once on a six port USB hub. I have never had any complaints or issues with them whether it be at home or among others people at my workplace. We can hot-swap any device on the hub with no problems. The one thing to consider though, is that bandwidth will be shared across all devices on a hub. This means that if you have two nice USB 3.0 (theoretically 5 Gbit/s) hard drives running on a hub transferring information to each other, they will only transfer at 2.5 Gbit/s each (under optimal theoretical conditions).

Comment: While the anecdotes are nice in an IT environment, it doesn't give a very technical foundation for the reliability of USB hubs. Can you expand your answer to better address the question?